# filling a collection using an iterator

Tags: java, collections, guava

Google Collections has an [Iterables](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html) utility class for taking in a collection and iterable and putting all the elements from iterable into the collection, called `addAll`.   Is there something similar when all you have is an iterator?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, and it's called `Iterators.addAll(Collection, Iterator)`, unsurprisingly.

Comment: Beat me to it; here's the link from my answer:  http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html

Comment: Ah, I wasn't finding the Iterators class.  Guess I should have looked at the docs closer. :-)

Comment: Also, if your purpose is to fill up a collection that you won't change later, you can use ImmutableSet.copyOf(Iterator), etc.

Comment: according to the Iterables javadoc:  "Except as noted, each method has a corresponding Iterator-based method in the Iterators class."